# why 502 Error occurs just in product mode in next.js?

Tags: next.js, url-rewriting, http-status-code-502

I'm making a website by using next.js.
After deploying my project by Vercel, login api gives me 502 error.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [process.env.ORIGINAL_DATA, process.env.CONVERT_DATA]
  },
  swcMinify: true,
  env: {
    ORIGINAL_DATA : `https://${process.env.ORIGINAL_DATA}`,
    CONVERT_DATA : `https://${process.env.CONVERT_DATA}`,
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: `http://${process.env.API}api/:path*`,
      },
      {
        source: "/video/:filename*",
        destination: `https://${process.env.CONVERT_DATA}:filename*`,
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

My config codes are here.
In development mode, it does work.
Does anyone know why this is happening??
is there something wrong in rewrites fnc??

I double checked env variables...
I've cleaned cache and cookies...

Comment: Self-Solved : my env API was something like "44.222.222.200:3333/" and I changed it to "http://http://44.222.222.200:3333/api/:path*" and just left process.env.API for destination. it works. does anyone know why??